# Remove string like space + letter+ space from a dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have those sentences column in a dataframe:

```
"I love x cat"
"You x x"
"x x x x"
"This example is better"
```

And I would like with python remove " x "

```
"I love cat"
"You"
""
"This example is better"
```

But I don't know how could I get it because the word example has "x" and I don't want to remove it

Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: `' '.join(filter('x'.__ne__, the_string.split()))`

Comment: @ojdo In case it is a homework problem, and a student copies the code without understanding it, then this way the teacher is more likely to notice, and the student is less likely to be able to explain the code they submitted. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've a dataframe then you can use:

```
df['your col name here'] = df['your col name here'].apply(lambda s: ' '.join(i for i in s.split(' ') if i != 'x'))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
my_string = "I love x cat"
my_list = my_string.split(' ')
new_list = [word for word in my_list if word != 'x']
new_string = ' '.join(new_list)
```

Comment: Oh! it works! but I have a data frame column with those sentences. How could I apply to a df?

Comment: @mathprogram If your data is in a dataframe, state that *in your question*

Comment: You can put the above solution into a function and apply the function to the column: df['column'] = df['column'].apply(function). The function takes a string as input ('I love x cat') and outputs the new string ('I love cat')

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the preceding space also, this would work as long as your word didn't start with an "x", you could also look for the following space with the same issue in reverse.

A third option is that you could also use replace to search for " x " and replace with a single space.

ref: https://www.dummies.com/programming/python/how-to-search-within-a-string-in-python/